# how to add pattern validation in angular

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-directive

I am having a model with a float propert

public float Amount { get; set; }

and a text box to display anf edit the value of amount.

only number accepted

my text box should allow characters and on while entering it should show error message

here i want to add a validation to restrict only number and decimal point.
here my validation is not working when i enter characters in the text box.

When i checked i can see that upon entering characters on text box {{model.amount}} is turned to blank . I think this is the problem. Can someone suggest what to do in this scenario

Comment: <input type="text" name="price" class="col-md-2 input-text" data-ng-model="price | currency:'' "  maxlength="4"  />
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('costCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.price = 11.2;
});
</script>

Comment: I have modified the textbox to format the number entering to format it to two decimal point. Actual requirement is to restrict entering decimal point through keybor(which i have done using directive) and on dispalying the number it should format to 2 decimal /float number . I have used currency and number:2 on my data-ng-model . But it is making my field to read only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can add ng-patter or add html5 input type number with step attr.

HTML5

```
<input type="number" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="myDecimal" *step="0.01"* />
```

ng-pattern

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="test1"  data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" data-ng-model="model.amount" /> 
  <span data-ng-show="myForm.test1.$error.pattern">invalid</span> 
  <span>{{model.amount}}</span><br/>
</form>
```

Ng-pattern with min and max

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="test1"  data-ng-pattern="/^(100(?:\.00)?|0(?:\.\d\d)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d\d)?)$/" data-ng-model="model.amount" /> 
    <span data-ng-show="myForm.test1.$error.pattern">invalid</span> 
    <span>{{model.amount}}</span><br/>
</form>
```

Please check working Ex. here 
https://plnkr.co/edit/WSqMHsLSCkRk7VVsNfHQ?p=preview

Comment: it is not firing the validation message.

Comment: add this tag inside the form tag and then check it again. I also update Ans.

Comment: <input type="text" name="test1" class="col-md-4" data-ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" data-ng-model="model.amount" />
                <span  data-ng-show="test1.$error.pattern">invalid</span>

                  <span>{{model.amount}}</span><br/> this doenst not display anything if i enter characters

Comment: type = number restricts the textbox from entering the characters . it allows only numbers. My requirement is to allow textbox to enter characters and display validation message

Comment: I've have added working plnkr for your given code please find it

Comment: Have you checked it's work or not according to your requiremt ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136829/discussion-between-manoj-patidar-and-jubi).

Comment: Thanks for the working plnkr. It worked. I was missing the Form name. i have modified the div with data-ng-form name="myForm" and it worked.

Comment: Can i add a maximum value validation for the same textbox . My type should be text and not number

Comment: Yes you can also add ng-maxlength on the input type.

Comment: Not lenght , the value., the range. Like amount cannot be greater than 100.

Comment: Can you highlight the change please

Comment: <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="test1"  data-ng-pattern="/^(100(?:\.00)?|0(?:\.\d\d)?|\d?\d(?:\.\d\d)?)$/" data-ng-model="model.amount" /> 
    <span data-ng-show="myForm.test1.$error.pattern">invalid</span> 
    <span>{{model.amount}}</span><br/>
</form>

Comment: i have change ng-pattern regular expr. please use this expr. it will work for you

Comment: my req is if i enter characters it should show one error message saying characters not allowed
and if entered number is greater than 100 it should show another message

Comment: Also the reqular expression allows spca at the beginning and end.

Comment: Patikar I am new to angular and trying to learn. I have tried <input type="text" ng-model="myNum">
<p class="bad-input" ng-if="parse(myNum)>10 ||parse(myNum)<0 ">The number is wrong</p> . with this i am getting validation message but it is not setting $error ppty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-pattern` to do this. It will compare the ng-model value with the pattern each time the value changes.

See the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

Answer (score 0):

Try referring this:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) { 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2>Validation Example</h2>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" 
name="myForm" novalidate>

<p>Enter Decimal:<br>
<input type="number" name="decimal" ng-model="decimal" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/">
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.decimal.$dirty && myForm.decimal.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.decimal.$error.required">please enter decimal value.</span>
<span ng-show="myForm.decimal.$invalid">only two decimal places are allwed.</span>
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit"
ng-disabled="myForm.decimal.$dirty && myForm.decimal.$invalid">
</p>

</form>
```